# Trouble accessing environment variable in VSCode for API_URL in .env.local file

Tags: next.js, environment-variables, next.js13, .env, next.js14

I am encountering an issue while trying to access a custom environment variable in my VSCode setup. I have a .env.local file in my project, where I've defined the variable like this:
`API_URL=https://example.com`
However, when I attempt to access this variable in my VSCode environment, I don't receive recommendations from VSCode's IntelliSense, unlike with NODE_ENV and TZ. It seems like VSCode is not recognizing or suggesting my custom environment variable.

Here's a snippet of my code where I'm trying to access the variable:
`axiosClient.ts`
[image]

I have verified that the .env.local file is properly configured and been set at top level directory, and the variable is set correctly. My project is running smoothly, however i couldn't access my API_URL does the issue related to new Next.js Server & Client Component?
Any guidance or insights into resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

i've try to create `.env` `.env.development` `.env.production` insted of **`.env.local`**
also i've changed the file extension from `ts` to `tsx`